# Автоматическая обрезка текста (text overflow)

Tags: html, css

Есть 2 div'a, в них находятся произвольный текст. Иногда они наезжают друг на друга, и я добавил `text-overflow` для ограничения длины этих блоков

Мне необходимо, чтобы текст автоматически обрезался, если рядом находится блок который не влазит в общий родительский `div`, но без указания `width/max-width` для этих блоков? Потому что с указанием максимальной длины, если есть пустое место, то строка в одном из блоков всё равно обрезается.

Comment: Минимальный код приведи. Не до конца понятно, как всё зрительно устроено.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант - flex:

```css
.wrapper{
    display: flex;
}
.wrapper > div{
    white-space: nowrap; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class=wrapper>
<div>Актуализация, очевидно, расточительно переворачивает неоднозначный мир.</div>
<div>Уравнение в частных производных</div>
</div>
```

Когда один тест обрезан, другой нет:

```css
.wrapper{
    display: flex;
}
.wrapper > div{
    white-space: nowrap; 
}
.wrapper > div.cut{
    overflow: hidden; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class=wrapper>
<div class=cut>Актуализация, очевидно, расточительно переворачивает неоднозначный мир.</div>
<div class=full>Уравнение в частных производных</div>
</div>
```